# post hoc test following linear mixed effect regression: stata code?

Tags: stata, posthoc

I am trying to figure out the code to do a post hoc test (Bonferroni adjusted) in Stata following my linear mixed effects model. I believe the `margins` command can be used? Does anyone know how I can do this?

My code below didn't work, error: option bonferroni not allowed. All pe has three groups, and I want to see the differences between groups in final_hc variable

```
mixed final_hc age0 age0_2 all_pe || cidb3035: age0, cov(unstructured)

// Estimate marginal means
margins, at(all_pe=(0 1 2)) post

// Adjust for multiple comparisons (Bonferroni)
adjust all_pe: margins, bonferroni
```

i have since tried this:

```
margins r.all_pe, plot
```

But i am still unsure how to get the Bonferroni correction. i needed to add i. to all_pe (i.all_pe) in my first model to make this work.

Comment: The problem report "didn't work" should be explained please. An error message? Results but not what you wanted? Something else? Equally important: this isn't based on a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Questions on what statistical approach to use are off-topic here. Please consider using Cross Validated. Alternatively, Statalist is very open to questions that mix Stata and statistics.

Comment: Thank Nick, I have edited my question

Comment: The syntax appears to `mcompare(bonferroni)` not `bonferroni`.

Comment: Thank Nick, i have just tried the following but it says mcompare is not allowed
adjust all_pe: margins, mcompare(bonferroni)
option mcompare() not allowed

Comment: i have also tried the following but no success:
pwcompare all_pe, effects mcompare(bonferroni)
variable all_pe not found

the variable is in my dataset, so error is weird

Comment: You've gone beyond my expertise. If you don't get a better response, I strongly recommend Statalist with many more members who use `margins` routinely.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, really appreciate you taking the time!